# How to call a method of component inside a function of an event in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket

I have the following `ChatPanelComponent` in which I have a created `getSocket` method to get a socket and called the `onopen` EventListener when the socket is connected.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit, QueryList, ViewChild, ViewChildren, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { FuseSidebarService } from '@fuse/components/sidebar/sidebar.service';
import { FusePerfectScrollbarDirective } from '@fuse/directives/fuse-perfect-scrollbar/fuse-perfect-scrollbar.directive';
import { ChatPanelService } from 'app/layout/components/chat-panel/chat-panel.service';
import { WebsocketService, UserService } from 'app/core/services';

@Component({
    selector     : 'chat-panel',
    templateUrl  : './chat-panel.component.html',
    styleUrls    : ['./chat-panel.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ChatPanelComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy
{
   contacts: any[];
   chat: any;
   selectedContact: any;
   ws: any;
   ws_url: any;
   user_id: any;
   
   constructor(
        private _chatPanelService: ChatPanelService,
        private _user: UserService,
        private _WebSocket: WebsocketService,
   )

   ngOnInit(): void
   {
       this.ws_url = 'http://localhost:8000/thread/';
       this.user_id = this._user.getUser().id;
       this.getSocket(this.user_id);
   }

   getSocket(id: any) {
       this.ws = this._WebSocket.connect(this.ws_url+id+'/');
 
       this.ws.onopen = function(e){
           console.log("WEBSOCKET OPEN", e);
       }

       this.ws.onmessage = function(e) {
           this.showMessage(e);
       }
  }

  showMessage(msg: any){
       console.log("MESSAGE", msg);
  }
}
```

I want to call the `showMessage(msg: any)` method when the `onmessage` event occurs and and pass the event data to the `showMessage()` method. But when the method is called it gives the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.showMessage is not a function
    at WebSocket.ws.onmessage [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYmessage]
```

I can't think of any other ways to call the method. I need help in this.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using  arrow function? It   preserves the context.

`this.ws.onmessage = (e) => {  this.showMessage(e);  }`

Comment: Thank You maidi! this worked for me. The message is getting printed on console now.

Answer (score 1):

Because event callbacks are executed outside Angular's context, `this` refers to callback event's context rather than angular components. so `this` does not refers to component's context anymore.

you can save value of `this` inside any other local variable and use that:

```
getSocket(id: any) {
       this.ws = this._WebSocket.connect(this.ws_url+id+'/');
 
       this.ws.onopen = function(e){
           console.log("WEBSOCKET OPEN", e);
       }

       const self = this; // <- store this value in a local variable

       this.ws.onmessage = function(e) {
           self.showMessage(e); //<- use that local variable containing value of component's context
       }
}
```

For more detail about it please refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/9722122

Comment: Thank You Mustahsan your method worked for me. Thanks a lot!